# Escaping from a nested material-ui dialog

Tags: material-ui

When I have one dialog open and it opens another and I hit escape it closes both.

Is there any way to make the escape only close the top most dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think this will be possible without some hassle. In the dialog render function, this eventlistener is rendered and there is no prop that allows you to overwrite this.

```js
{open &&
   <EventListener
      target="window"
      onKeyUp={this.handleKeyUp}
      onResize={this.handleResize}
   />
}
```

Which calls this method.

```js
handleKeyUp = (event) => {
    if (keycode(event) === 'esc') {
      this.requestClose(false);
    }
};
```

[source](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/Dialog/Dialog.js)

You can however dive into in **node_modules/material-ui/Dialog/dialog.js** and delete that code or change it. Removing this line will prevent it from ever closing on esc, but will count for all dialogs. Maybe after that you can implement a keycode event listener in you own class that handles the closing of the modal.

```js
if ((0, _keycode2.default)(event) === 'esc') {
   _this2.requestClose(false);
}
```

EDIT: possible solution.

I created 2 components, a DialogContainer class component and a Dialog functional component. To use this you have to `npm install --save react-event-listener`.

**For this to work you still have to remove the above code from the node_modules**.

When only one dialog is opened it will close that dialog when esc is clicked. If two dialogs are opened it will first close dialog2 and leave dialog1 open.

**DialogContainer.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Dialog from './Dialog';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import EventListener from 'react-event-listener';

export default class DialogContainer extends Component {
  state = {
    openDialog1: false,
    openDialog2: false
  };

  handleDialog1Open = () => {
    this.setState({ openDialog1: true });
  };

  handleDialog2Open = () => {
    this.setState({ openDialog2: true });
  };

  handleDialog1Close = () => {
    this.setState({ openDialog1: false });
  };

  handleDialog2Close = () => {
    this.setState({ openDialog2: false });
  };

  handleKeyUp = (event) => {
    // 27 = esc
    if (event.keyCode === 27) {
      if (this.state.openDialog1 && this.state.openDialog2) {
        this.handleDialog2Close();
      } else {
        this.handleDialog1Close();
        this.handleDialog2Close();
      }
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
     <div>
       {(this.state.openDialog1 || this.state.openDialog2) &&
       <EventListener
        target="window"
        onKeyUp={this.handleKeyUp}
       />}
       <RaisedButton label="Open1" onTouchTap={this.handleDialog1Open}/>
       <RaisedButton label="Open2" onTouchTap={this.handleDialog2Open}/>
       <Dialog
        openOtherDialog={this.handleDialog2Open}
        open={this.state.openDialog1}
        handleClose={this.handleDialog1Close}
        number={1}/>
       <Dialog
        open={this.state.openDialog2}
        handleClose={this.handleDialog2Close}
        number={2}/>
     </div>
    )
  }
};
```

**Dialog.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import Dialog from 'material-ui/Dialog';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';

const DialogCustom = ({ open, handleClose, number, openOtherDialog}) => {
  return (
   <div>
     <Dialog
      title="Dialog"
      modal={false}
      open={open}
      onRequestClose={handleClose}
     >
       {`this is dialog ${number}`}
       {openOtherDialog &&
       <RaisedButton label="Open2" onTouchTap={openOtherDialog}/>
       }
     </Dialog>
   </div>
  );
};

export default DialogCustom;
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this!

Answer (score 0):

There is nearly always a better solution than having two dialogs/modals open at the same time. In our material-design app using MUI, we have this situation on a few occasions. The way we handle it: close the "underneath" dialog when the "top" dialog opens. Then (if needed), you can re-open the "underneath" dialog when closing the "top" dialog. Seems like a lot of work, but stacking dialogs gets to be tricky with both the code and the UX considerations.